# Natural alkaline foods

Tags: food-science

Is there any naturally occuring food which is alkaline?

Searching the internet for this seems to be futile as every search result talks about alkaline diets, i.e. things that generate an alkaline response in the stomach after eating them.

I'm interested in those which would show blue on a litmus test. (Like sodium bicarbonate, but natural substances)

Comment: I'd guess it relates to the prevalence of toxic alkaloids in plants, somehow https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/19147309/

Comment: @fyrepenguin yes it does. Thanks. Better to close this question/duplicate it